# Page postback even after showing validation summary

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a masterpage, having same old header, footer and content sections. I have different aspx pages bases on this masterpage. But each aspx contains a web user control.

For ex. MasterPage -> SiteMaster.master,
  ASPX -> CreateBid.aspx,
  Web Control -> CreateBid.ascx.

I have used validation controls within web controls showing validation summary within the same control.
The problem here is that, the page postbacks even if validation fails. The validation summary is also shown, but page is postbacked.

Could someone help me why this is happening?

Although the page is postbacked, no code is executed. For ex. If i am clicking on Submit button, nothing is submitted, i could see the validation summary or messagebox but the page is refreshed. If i am considering simple aspx without masterpage the validation works perfectly without page refresh.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Comment: How did you fix this?  I am running into the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hai Raza,

> Have a look at this it may be your answer [Validators on postback](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/ie_validators.aspx)

Comment: I am reading that, but still my problem not solved. Please read my edits to question.

Comment: What u did to overcome the issue?